# How to print number of occurances of a word in a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

This is my shell script.
Given a directory, and a word, search the directory and print the absolute path of the file that has the maximum occurrences of the word and also print the number of occurrences. 
I have written the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

 if [[ -n $(find / -type d -name $1 2> /dev/null) ]]
 then
  echo "Directory exists"

   x=` echo " $(find / -type d -name $1 2> /dev/null)"`
   echo "$x"
   cd $x
   y=$(find . -type f | xargs grep -c  $2  | grep -v ":0"| grep -o '[^/]*$' | sort -t: -k2,1 -n -r ) 
   echo "$y"
   else 
   echo "Directory does does not exists"
 fi   


 result: scriptname directoryname word
 output: /somedirectory/vtb/wordsearch : 4
         /foo/bar: 3
```

Is there any option to replace xargs grep -c $2 ? Because grep -c prints the count=number of lines which contains the word but i need to print the exact occurrence of a word in the files in a given directory

Comment: Running that find command twice is a mistake. `x=\`echo "$(find ...)"\`` can just be `x=$(find ...)`. Grabbing the output of find like that isn't safe for files with spaces or other special characters.

Comment: it does not work if i remove that

Comment: How so? That wrapping `echo` and extra sub-shell aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using grep's `-c` count feature:

```
grep -c "SEARCH" /path/to/files* | sort -r -t : -k 2 | head -n 1
```

The grep command will output each file in a `/path/name:count` format, the sort will numerically (`-n`) sort by the 2nd (`-k 2`) field as delimited by a colon (`-t :`) in reverse order (`-r`).  We then use head to keep the first result (`-n 1`).

Comment: Does it search for the files containing the given word in the current directory recursively ? Because i am not specifying any path for files. Sorry i cant run the command and check as i am at home so wanted to clarify my doubt

Comment: `grep -c` only counts **lines** containing the pattern, not all occurrences of the pattern if it occurs more than once per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Fwor "$word" "$dir" | sed "s/:${word}\$//" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: what does sed is doing and i dunno what {word} indicates

Comment: `grep -o -r` outputs the filename, a colon, and the word you're looking for. That `sed` removes the colon and the word -- I'm not assuming that every filename is free from colons.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
grep -o -w 'foo' bar.txt | wc -w
```

OR

```
grep -o -w 'word' /path/to/file/ | wc -w
```

Comment: This prints only the number of times the word present in a given file. But i need to print file name and the count.